# Validating a UK date using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, date

I have two jQuery datepickers that once changed, will trigger some ajax to grab all information between the two dates.

I want to run some code to check that the first date is smaller than the second, by converting to a date using this code:

```
function FormatUkDate(dateStr) { 
    dateStr = dateStr.split("/");
    return new Date(dateStr[2], dateStr[1] - 1, dateStr[0]);
}
```

This works great, but the problem is even if I enter a date of '50/08/2011' it still validates and converts that to a Javascript date, I believe by adding the additional number of days to the start date.

Is there a way to properly validate this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can validate using a jquery masked plugin,you can check it http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: Many thanks, I am using this but it only validates that it's a number and in the right format, not that I didn't enter 70/01/2011 etc :(

Comment: Sorry for that, you can try this http://nopogs.blogspot.com/2011/03/plugin-jquery-date-mask.html

Answer (score 1):

For working with dates you can try to use [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) library. It has many features including validating dates. To solve your problem you can use `Date.validateDay` method. Also you can use datejs to compare dates.

Answer (score 1):

hm... I guess a plugin would be a better solution, but for what it's worth:

```
function FormatUkDate(dateStr) { 
    dateStr = dateStr.split("/");
    var newDate = new Date(dateStr[2], dateStr[1] - 1, dateStr[0]);
    return newDate.getDate() == Number(dateStr[0]) && newDate.getMonth() == Number(dateStr[1]) - 1? newDate : null;
}
```

returns null if the date carries over to the next month.

#### Edit

New code :P

Comment: Many thanks for this, could be a perfect solution but unfortunately it always returns a null for me? Even (for example) using 02/08/2011 as a date

Comment: @xn dx Sorry about that. I fixed the code... should work now.

Comment: This is perfect now, thank you so much! A great way to validate dates :)